# How to authorize with the LinkedIn JavaScript SDK on the front-end without exposing your API key?

Tags: api, authorization, linkedin-api, signing, api-key

As described in their [official JavaScript documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#initialize), the way you should authorize users through their LinkedIn account is by placing this script in your front-end files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [API_KEY]
    onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
    authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```

Now the problem with this is that you obviously expose your API key to everyone using your app.

I'm having a hard time squaring this in my mind because you cannot have this script on the front-end without revealing your API key, which can be used to access data on all users having authorized your application.

Should you maybe load this script via a proxy? But then why do they explicitly tell us to put the script in the head section in your HTML?

Your input is much appreciated :)